# K-state-focus on kendo window , screen

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

when k-state-focus is enabled for kendo window and we press any arrow key then screen start moving on that direction how to restrict movement of window upto parent window on pressing arrow keys?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to disable Dragable option to prevent window from moving.

https://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-keyboard-from-moving-window